# Sequelize - User model with 2 addresses as foreign keys in a SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have trouble to make a more efficient/cleaner way to insert and find users. 
I have a user table where I have: id, mail, password, billing_address (foreign key), shipping_address (foreign key)
For now, it creates the user then it creates the addresses separately and then it updates the user.billing_address and user.shipping_address with the addresses id.

Now my question is can I make a class method of the user where i have example user.create and user.find which does that job.

```
db.user = require('../models/user')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.address = require('../models/addresses')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.user.hasMany(db.address);
db.address.belongsTo(db.user);
```

the models are defined like this: 
User

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {..attributes..}, {
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: function(user) {
        try
        {
          if(!user.changed('password')) return sequelize.Promise.reject('not modified');

          var hash = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password);

          user.setDataValue('password', hash);
        }
        catch(e)
        {console.error("Big one");}
      },
    }
  });
  return User;
};
```

Address:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Addresses = sequelize.define('Addresses', {..attributes..}, {
    underscored: true,
  });
  return Addresses;
};
```

I want something like this to accomplish:
db.user.create() - it should create a user and the addresses for the user and give an object back with all information.
db.user.find() - it should find a user with the user id, and give all the addresses back from that user and not just their id's.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would do this in sequelize but this kind of thing is quite straightforward with [sworm](https://github.com/featurist/sworm)

```
var person = db.model({table: 'people'});
var address = db.model({table: 'addresses'});

var bob = person({
  name: 'bob',
  address: address({
    address: 'Fremantle'
  })
});

bob.save()
```

This would result in:

```
-------- people ----------
| id | name | address_id |
--------------------------
| 11 | bob  | 22         |
--------------------------

------- addresses ------
| id | address         |
------------------------
| 22 | Fremantle       |
------------------------
```